# How to "redecorate" (shade/unshade) an application when accidentally disabled 18.04

Tags: 18.04, window, titlebar

How does one "redecorate" (shade/unshade) an application when accidentally disabled in Kubuntu 18.04? [screenshot showing no titlebar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Loim.jpg) I don't appear to have Openbox or Compiz installed. The app I want to restore the titlebar menu on is Firefox. Without it I can't resize the borders, etc.
Thank you.

Comment: You did not by accident put firefox in full screen? Press F11 to switch back from full screen to windowed (and again to go full screen)

Comment: no. F11 has no effect on this. if you right-click on Firefox in the taskbar and choose "more actions" "shade" is grayed out.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to backup my bookmarks, passwords, and extension settings and restore Firefox to a virginal state using the following command:
$ rm -r -v ~/.mozilla && rm -r -v ~/.cache/mozilla